# delay sending emails with php

Tags: php, mysql, email, delayed-execution

So I have a code that checks the records on a table and emails them.
table1 fields are: id - userid - email - subject - txt
the code is as follow (simplified):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 where userid='$userid'";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{
mail($row['email'],$row['subject'],$row['txt']);
}
```

this will send all the emails at once.
I want it to be able to send emails with random delays.
for example : send the first email,wait 1 hour, send the second, wait 2 hours, send email 3
wait 5hours, send email 5 then wait 2hours ...
I was thinking about using the function `rand();`
but I have no idea how to implement the delay ... 
any thoughts? I appreciate any input

Comment: Create a table with scheduled emails, create random sending time and send them by dedicated worker

Comment: Depending on the volume of email you plan on sending, consider using a different storage engine for your messaging queue.  For instance, you may consider using MongoDB or Couch for your message queue if you are using Oracle or MySQL for your site data.

Comment: @Travis: what's wrong with using oracle or mysql for emails schedule?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. I mention it because in my current job we use Oracle for transactional data, and we use MongoDB for our email  queue, reporting data, caching, and a few other minor things. 

In the event that there is an intensive query for those minor things it won't have an impact on the more important transactional work that Oracle takes care of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate random numbers, add them in hour format to a timestamp, and save them in the database.

You can do this using the PHP `rand()` function and mysql (specifically this mysql code: `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $randInteger HOUR)` )

Run a script every hour that checks with the database if there is an email that should be sent/which email to send and then does based on the information it returns.

You can do this using cron (you have this in cpanel if you have a host that provides cpanel)